# RAID-1 / LVM server won't boot after power outage

Tags: boot, mount, software-raid, lvm, raid1

Strange issue.  After an extended power outage (transformer exploded!) which outlasted the UPS, a server running Slackware 13 crashed.  This machine has been quietly serving accounting software and file storage in a multiuser environment since December of 2009 with NO ISSUES!

This machine has two 500GB SATA disks set up using **LVM** on top of software *RAID1* (all done by slackware installer).  When power is applied, the `initrd image` loads properly, but the boot fails when it's time to mount the root filesystem.

```
"Failed to mount /dev/Volume00/RootVol on /mnt.  No such device or directory."
```

RootVol is a logical volume in volume group Volume00.  There are 3 other LV filesystems plus swap in this volume group.  I can mount any of them from the `boot#_ prompt` and they appear fine.  However, RootVol, the root filesystem, does not show up at all... `/dev/mapper/Volume00` lists the other 4 but RootVol is missing.

So, I booted up a linux rescue cd.  The RAID1 volume `/dev/md0` comes up, and lo and behold, I can see, and mount, `/dev/Volume00/RootVol`.

Now, `/proc/mdstat` shows that `/dev/md0` is running degraded, using only device `/dev/dm-1`.  I'm not sure if this means that I'm down a disk... I am accustomed to seeing actual hard drives in /proc/mdstat... /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, etc. on non-LVM arrays.  How can I determine which disk has failed?  How do `/dev/dm-x` devices relate to `/dev/sdx` devices?  And how can I get the machine to boot from the remaining disk, which (appears to) be fine.  The two hard drives used in the array are /dev/sda and /dev/sdb, entire disks.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial on /dev/dm-x devices?  I see they are LVM devices from the *dmsetup* documentation but don't want to start messing with anything without a good understanding of what I'm doing.  I thought RAID was built on physical devices, then volume groups built on raid devices... I cannot fathom why there would be LVM devices showing as elements of a disk array but I'm sure there's a damned good reason... or a fundamental misunderstanding on my part.

Here's some info:

Output of cat /dev/mdstat is:

```
root@sysresccd /mnt/rootvol/etc % cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]         [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 dm-1[0]
488287488 blocks [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>
```

Not what I expected. My two hard drives are /dev/sda and /dev/sdb, no errors in /var/log/messages about them although I have no ability to tweak loglevels in the Live CD version I am running. Why does /proc/mdstat not show actual devices? What are /dev/dm-# devices?

Output of mdadm --detail /dev/md0 is:

```
root@sysresccd /mnt/rootvol/etc % dmadm -D /dev/md0
zsh: correct 'dmadm' to 'mdadm' [nyae]? y
/dev/md0:
Version : 0.90
Creation Time : Thu Dec 3 11:53:48 2009
Raid Level : raid1
Array Size : 488287488 (465.67 GiB 500.01 GB)
Used Dev Size : 488287488 (465.67 GiB 500.01 GB)
Raid Devices : 2
Total Devices : 1
Preferred Minor : 0
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Sun Jul 10 12:00:57 2016
State : clean, degraded 
Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

UUID : a89cbdf5:f83cf3f7:dcc86dce:213c81b2
Events : 0.38

Number Major Minor RaidDevice State
0 253 1 0 active sync /dev/dm-1
2 0 0 2 removed
```

I am guessing that either a) I have a failed disk or b) the array /dev/md0 is not synched, maybe thinks a disk has failed?

At any rate, the machine definitely will not boot from this state, and I can't figure out which, if any, of my hard disks are the problem, nor how to fix this mess. This is a production server with full backups... I could rebuild it, but really would rather not as it's a pretty tedious process... there's nothing wrong with the data nor, I'm guessing, either of the disks.

There is no `mdadm.conf`.

`fdisk -l` shows both disks as Linux Raid Autodetect, everything looks normal.

Output of `dmsetup` is (???'s inserted by me):

```
root@sysresccd /mnt/rootvol/etc % dmsetup ls 
isw_bfdbfijegh_Volume01 (253:1)
isw_bfdbfijegh_Volume0  (253:0)
Volume00-MediaVol   (253:9)
Volume00-RootSnap-cow   (253:4) <-- ??? --- "cow" --- ???
Volume00-XplrVol    (253:7)
Volume00-RootSnap   (253:5)
Volume00-SwapVol    (253:8)
Volume00-RootVol    (253:3)
Volume00-RootVol-real   (253:2) <--- ??? --- "real" --- ???
Volume00-HomeVol    (253:6)
```

I posted the info below as a reply, but it was suggested I edit this original post and add it in so here it is:

Here is `dmsetup` table:

```
root@sysresccd /mnt/usbhdd1/server_backup/oldroot % dmsetup table
isw_bfdbfijegh_Volume01: 0 976575222 linear 253:0 63
isw_bfdbfijegh_Volume0: 0 976767240 mirror core 2 131072 nosync 2 8:0 0    8:16 0 1 handle_errors
Volume00-MediaVol: 0 209715200 linear 9:127 134218112
Volume00-RootSnap-cow: 0 2097152 linear 9:127 385876352
Volume00-XplrVol: 0 41943040 linear 9:127 83886464
Volume00-RootSnap: 0 20971520 snapshot 253:2 253:4 P 8
Volume00-SwapVol: 0 8388608 linear 9:127 125829504
Volume00-RootVol: 0 20971520 snapshot-origin 253:2
Volume00-RootVol-real: 0 20971520 linear 9:127 384
Volume00-HomeVol: 0 62914560 linear 9:127 20971904
Volume00-HomeVol: 62914560 41943040 linear 9:127 343933312
```

And here is `mdadm -E` for each hard drive.

```
root@sysresccd /mnt/usbhdd1/server_backup/oldroot % mdadm -E /dev/sda
mdmon: /dev/sda is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdmon: /dev/sda is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
/dev/sda:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.1.00
    Orig Family : 5b4a335b
         Family : 5b4a335b
     Generation : 0000000a
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 15980595:45ac18ac:22467c90:56138fde
       Checksum : c51f833a correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 2
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk00 Serial : WD-WCASY8349657
          State : active
             Id : 00000000
    Usable Size : 976767240 (465.76 GiB 500.10 GB)

[Volume0]:
           UUID : 4b19b799:c2a34a28:0bcca120:36d318a0
     RAID Level : 1
        Members : 2
          Slots : [UU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 0
     Array Size : 976766976 (465.76 GiB 500.10 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 976767240 (465.76 GiB 500.10 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 3815496
     Chunk Size : 64 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : uninitialized
    Dirty State : clean

  Disk01 Serial : WD-WCASY8288673
          State : active
             Id : 00010000
    Usable Size : 976767240 (465.76 GiB 500.10 GB)


root@sysresccd /mnt/usbhdd1/server_backup/oldroot % mdadm -E /dev/sdb
mdmon: /dev/sdb is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdmon: /dev/sdb is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.1.00
    Orig Family : 5b4a335b
         Family : 5b4a335b
     Generation : 0000000a
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 15980595:45ac18ac:22467c90:56138fde
       Checksum : c51f833a correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 2
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk01 Serial : WD-WCASY8288673
          State : active
             Id : 00010000
    Usable Size : 976767240 (465.76 GiB 500.10 GB)

[Volume0]:
           UUID : 4b19b799:c2a34a28:0bcca120:36d318a0
     RAID Level : 1
        Members : 2
          Slots : [UU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 1
     Array Size : 976766976 (465.76 GiB 500.10 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 976767240 (465.76 GiB 500.10 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 3815496
     Chunk Size : 64 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : uninitialized
    Dirty State : clean

  Disk00 Serial : WD-WCASY8349657
          State : active
             Id : 00000000
    Usable Size : 976767240 (465.76 GiB 500.10 GB)
```

Wouldn't `initrd` already have --assemble  in it?  The array is up even when I can't mount the root volume... the other 3 volumes I CAN mount and they're in the same VG on the same RAID1 array... why can I mount `/dev/Volume00/RootVol` when booted from rescue CD vs. booting from disk?

Comment: Could we get `dmsetup table` and also, `mdadm -E /dev/sd[ab]*`. I'd *guess* the recovery disk has done something weird (read: *wrong*) in how it set up LVM and RAID. I'd guess an `mdadm --assemble «something»` from the initrd would work...

Comment: And yes, `/dev/dm-*` is Device Mapper, which is the underlying technology behind LVM, and several other things. "cow" (= copy-on-write) and "real" are from having an LVM snapshot.

Comment: Dave, it also appears that you have two unregistered accounts; I approved your edit but you'll want to confirm one of them then ask for them to be [merged](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Try `vgchange -ay` and see what happens.  Please also add output of `pvdisplay -m` and `lvs`.  But my recommendation is:  First do a backup of *both* disks using `ddrescue` (sometimes called `gddrescue`).  You can attach storage for this using `sshfs` (if you have a stable network connection) or do it the other way round (mount the `/dev` from the server via `sshfs` and do the `ddrescue` on the other side, but this is slower and less intuitive).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I currently see that mounting another `/dev` is not possible with `sshfs`, sigh.  I did this with some obscure python and will upload this soon to GitHub: https://github.com/hilbix/sshcopydev

Comment: Also, your drives are 6.5 years old - overdue for replacement.  The smallest HDD replacement you can get these days is 1TB for around $60-$100.  If you don't need any more storage space but would benefit from more I/O performance, replace them with SATA3 SSDs - from $200-$300 for 500GB.  1TB SSDs start from around $400.  BTW, LVM can do RAID-1 by itself, no need to layer it on top of mdadm.  When you rebuild (and you **should** rebuild, because your drives are too old to be trusted), you should use just LVM and not bother with mdadm.

Comment: @cas - I'm replacing the machine, it is being built with new 1TB drives.  I didn't have a good understanding of the whole dm/fakeraid concept when I originally built the machine (still don't but that's a topic for another day) and would not opt to use it... there is no apparent performance increase, just an added layer of complexity.  I still have no idea if I even have a failed drive, and why the machine won't boot off the remaining one especially if the BIOS RAID presents as a block device to the OS.